# real time - browser

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i have a problem, my search engine only searches with a particular Model

i need you to do the search on multiple models

**Model: 'Registro'**

```
       public function search(Request $request){
        
        $results = Registro::where('cliente', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")->get();
        

       

        foreach($results as $result){
      
            $res2 = Rawson::where('cliente', $result->cliente)->get();


        }

        $digits = [$res2, $results];
     
        dd($digits);
      


        return view('posts.results', compact('digits'))->with(['search' => $request->search])->render();
        
    }
```

**View Results:**

```
<ul class="list-unstyled w-100">
@forelse ($digits as $post)
<li><a href="#" class="post-link" data-id="{{ $post->id }}">{{ $post->cliente }}</a></li>
@empty
<li><a href="#" data-id="0">No hay resultados disponibles "{{ $search }}"</a></li>
@endforelse
```

dd Results:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlFLG.png

**How can I read the results of the array?**

help please

Answer (score 0):

i guess this will solve your issue, just make sure you put right column names for each table:

```
public function search(Request $request) {
    $registros = Registro::where('cliente', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")->get();
    $digits = Rawson::whereIn('cliente', $registros->pluck('cliente'))->get();
    return view('posts.results', compact('digits'))->with(['search' => $request->search])->render();
}
```

Comment: that way only get values from the 'Rawson' Model

Comment: @JeremiasRosas oh you want to search for both and mix them up in single array?

Comment: @JeremiasRosas ok i got you